# Parse iOS SDK Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." on mobile network

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I get this error in my iOS app using Parse SDK. The strange thing is that i only get this error when i'm NOT using wifi. On wifi it works just fine.

Could it be some bug with the Parse SDK version 1.5? Does anyone else get this error?

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." 
UserInfo=0x7fe8c2e25130 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe8c2c63940 "The network connection was lost.", 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.} 
(Code: 100, Version: 1.5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this with slow internet connections (3G especially) and when I had big sized objects like a table view with a lot high quality images. Sometimes it just happens without any serious reasons. I think it's a network issue not a Parse bug. Parse handles these situations very good, it tries to reconnect in every 2/3 seconds. International bandwidth can be a reason too, maybe you are far from the server.

Comment: Thats what i thought to - but it seems to have nothing do do with connectivity, since it produces the bug right away, with no loading time. I also found out that it works on all other devices except my dev. iPhone.

Comment: @tskippe I got it more frequently on my old iphone 4.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, this is to do with internet speed. when signal is low, this issue occurs. Sometime by refreshing network or close/opening the xcode does help.